# Fedora error log file

Tags: centos, java

I am running a java application using this wrapper service yajsw. The problem it just stopped without any error in its logs file. So I was wondering will there be any system log file which will indicate the cause of it going down?

```
Partial of the log file.

Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: imklog 3.22.1, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="3.22.1" x-pid="2234" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Linux version 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-4.fedora.phx.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Dec 10 10:36:29 EST 2009
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Command line: ro root=UUID=722ebf87-437f-4634-9c68-a82d157fa948 rhgb quiet
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  Intel GenuineIntel
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  AMD AuthenticAMD
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  Centaur CentaurHauls
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 00000000000a0000 (usable)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000cfb50000 (usable)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000cfb50000 - 00000000cfb66000 (reserved)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000cfb66000 - 00000000cfb85c00 (ACPI data)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000cfb85c00 - 00000000d0000000 (reserved)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000e0000000 - 00000000f0000000 (reserved)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000fe000000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 0000000330000000 (usable)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: DMI 2.5 present.
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: last_pfn = 0x330000 max_arch_pfn = 0x3ffffffff
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: last_pfn = 0xcfb50 max_arch_pfn = 0x3ffffffff
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: init_memory_mapping
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: last_map_addr: cfb50000 end: cfb50000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: init_memory_mapping
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: last_map_addr: 330000000 end: 330000000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: RAMDISK: 37bfc000 - 37fef6c8
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: RSDP 000F21B0, 0024 (r2 DELL  )
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: XSDT 000F224C, 0084 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: FACP CFB83524, 00F4 (r3 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: DSDT CFB66000, 4974 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 INTL 20050624)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: FACS CFB85C00, 0040
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: APIC CFB83078, 00B6 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: SPCR CFB83130, 0050 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: HPET CFB83184, 0038 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: MCFG CFB831C0, 003C (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: WD__ CFB83200, 0134 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: SLIC CFB83338, 0176 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: ERST CFB6AAF4, 0210 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: HEST CFB6AD04, 027C (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: BERT CFB6A974, 0030 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: EINJ CFB6A9A4, 0150 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: TCPA CFB834BC, 0064 (r1 DELL   PE_SC3          1 DELL        1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: No NUMA configuration found
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Faking a node at 0000000000000000-0000000330000000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Bootmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-0000000330000000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  NODE_DATA [0000000000015000 - 0000000000029fff]
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  bootmap [000000000002a000 -  000000000008ffff] pages 66
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: (7 early reservations) ==> bootmem [0000000000 - 0330000000]
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  #0 [0000000000 - 0000001000]   BIOS data page ==> [0000000000 - 0000001000]
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  #1 [0000006000 - 0000008000]       TRAMPOLINE ==> [0000006000 - 0000008000]
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  #2 [0000200000 - 0000a310cc]    TEXT DATA BSS ==> [0000200000 - 0000a310cc]
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  #3 [0037bfc000 - 0037fef6c8]          RAMDISK ==> [0037bfc000 - 0037fef6c8]
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  #4 [000009f000 - 0000100000]    BIOS reserved ==> [000009f000 - 0000100000]
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  #5 [0000008000 - 000000c000]          PGTABLE ==> [0000008000 - 000000c000]
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  #6 [000000c000 - 0000015000]          PGTABLE ==> [000000c000 - 0000015000]
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: found SMP MP-table at [ffff8800000fe710] 000fe710
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Zone PFN ranges:
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  DMA      0x00000000 -> 0x00001000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  DMA32    0x00001000 -> 0x00100000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:  Normal   0x00100000 -> 0x00330000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Movable zone start PFN for each node
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: early_node_map[3] active PFN ranges
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:    0: 0x00000000 -> 0x000000a0
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:    0: 0x00000100 -> 0x000cfb50
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel:    0: 0x00100000 -> 0x00330000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x808
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x04] enabled)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x06] enabled)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x05] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x06] lapic_id[0x05] enabled)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x07] lapic_id[0x03] enabled)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x08] lapic_id[0x07] enabled)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] high edge lint[0x1])
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x08] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 8, version 0, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x09] address[0xfec81000] gsi_base[64])
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: IOAPIC[1]: apic_id 9, version 0, address 0xfec81000, GSI 64-87
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x0a] address[0xfec84000] gsi_base[160])
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: IOAPIC[2]: apic_id 10, version 0, address 0xfec84000, GSI 160-183
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x0b] address[0xfec84800] gsi_base[224])
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: IOAPIC[3]: apic_id 11, version 0, address 0xfec84800, GSI 224-247
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Setting APIC routing to flat
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: SMP: Allowing 8 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000cfb50000 - 00000000cfb66000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000cfb66000 - 00000000cfb85000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000cfb85000 - 00000000cfb86000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000cfb86000 - 00000000d0000000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000d0000000 - 00000000e0000000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000e0000000 - 00000000f0000000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000f0000000 - 00000000fe000000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fe000000 - 0000000100000000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Allocating PCI resources starting at d1000000 (gap: d0000000:10000000)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PERCPU: Allocating 65184 bytes of per cpu data
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 3096524
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Policy zone: Normal
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Kernel command line: ro root=UUID=722ebf87-437f-4634-9c68-a82d157fa948 rhgb quiet
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Initializing CPU#0
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 12, 32768 bytes)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Extended CMOS year: 2000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: TSC: PIT calibration confirmed by PMTIMER.
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: TSC: using PMTIMER calibration value
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Detected 1994.992 MHz processor.
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: console [tty0] enabled
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Checking aperture...
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: No AGP bridge found
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Placing software IO TLB between 0x20000000 - 0x24000000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Memory: 12324244k/13369344k available (3311k kernel code, 253484k reserved, 1844k data, 1296k init)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: SLUB: Genslabs=13, HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=8, Nodes=1
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 3989.98 BogoMIPS (lpj=1994992)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Security Framework initialized
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: SELinux:  Initializing.
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Dentry cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 12, 16777216 bytes)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Inode-cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys ns
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU: L1 I cache: 32K, L1 D cache: 32K
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU: L2 cache: 4096K
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU 0/0 -> Node 0
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: using mwait in idle threads.
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ACPI: Core revision 20080609
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz stepping 07
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Using local APIC timer interrupts.
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Detected 20.781 MHz APIC timer.
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Booting processor 1/4 ip 6000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Initializing CPU#1
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 3990.05 BogoMIPS (lpj=1995026)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU: L1 I cache: 32K, L1 D cache: 32K
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU: L2 cache: 4096K
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU 1/4 -> Node 0
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU: Physical Processor ID: 1
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU1: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM2)
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: x86 PAT enabled: cpu 1, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: CPU1: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz stepping 07
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: checking TSC synchronization [CPU#0 -> CPU#1]: passed.
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Booting processor 2/2 ip 6000
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Initializing CPU#2
Apr  6 00:12:20 localhost kernel: Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 3990.05 BogoMIPS (lpj=1995029)
```

Comment: What is the application and do you have access to the source?

Answer (score 2):

- General Linux messages are logged at `/var/log/messages`

  - You may have a number of logs named `messages*` - the one that is simply named `messages` is the latest one. The other logs have a number after them that signify the date they were closed. For example, some of the logs on one of my servers are `messages-20120401` and `messages-20120325`. It's up to you to decide which period of time the application crashed and therefore which log to sift through.
- Kernel logs are at `/var/log/kern.log` (but that's highly unlikely to be your issue)

Comment: I am in var/log but which one to look into quite a number of it there? Any idea?

Comment: @user111196 I updated my answer.

Comment: I have updated the partial log file looks like there was a restart in the system right?

Comment: If its own log is too good for it, then it's extraordinarily unlikely that anything has been sent to syslog.  Java applications almost never make use of syslog.

Comment: So based on the log file can it be decide what went wrong?

Comment: @user111196 Probably not. The Java application is poorly designed if it doesn't log its behavior. The only way that logging would take place outside of the application is if it was an external source that was causing the fault. Sorry, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Could be due to the machine got restarted due to some reason? Thereafter we did not set to the java service to run automatically after restart

Comment: if indeed my jvm got crashed will there be a log file indicating this and where that will be stored?